# How to access slices of a 3d matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, matrix

I would like to store 592 47x47 arrays into a 47x47x592 Matrix. I created the 3d Matrix as follows:

```
int sizes[] = {47,47,592};
Mat 3dmat(3, sizes, CV_32FC1);
```

I then thought I could access it by using a set of ranges as in the following.

```
Range ranges[3];
ranges[0] = Range::all();
ranges[1] = Range::all();
ranges[2] = Range(x,x+1) //within a for loop.
Mat 2dmat = 3dmat(ranges);
```

However, when I try to use the copyTo function to input an existing data set, it does not work.

```
data.copyTo(2dmat); //data is my 47x47 matrix
```

The 3d matrix does not get updated when I do this.

Any information is appreciated! Thanks!

edit: I store the 592 matrices in this 3d matrix so that I can then later access each of the individual 47x47 matrices in another loop. So I would later do something of this sort:

```
2dmat = 3dmat(ranges);
2dmat.copyTo(data);
```

So I would then perform some operations using this data matrix. And in the next iteration of the loop, I would use the next stored data matrix.

Comment: An alternative solution will be to store this 592 matrices in simple vector. And it will definitely work in the way it is suitable for you.

Comment: @marol I would contend that `vector` is a far better solution than what the OP is attempting. OpenCV becomes unwieldy when attempting to use more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! What exactly is the format for creating a vector of this sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative, vector-based solution:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> mat(592, cv::Mat(47, 47, CV_32FC1)); // allocates 592 matrices sized 47 by 47
for(auto &m: mat) {
    // do your processsing here
    data.copyTo(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the proper size of the slice, you should be good to go:

```
cv::Mat slice = mat3D(ranges).clone();
cv::Mat mat2D;
mat2D.create(2, &(mat3D.size[0]), mat3D.type());
slice.copySize(mat2D);
```

Now slice contains your 2D slice.

Comment: When I then try data.copyTo(slice), the original 3d matrix does not get updated. data is copied to slice, but this does not alter the 3d matrix, which I would like it to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. You just want a reference to that slice of the data, so you can perform operations and then re-set the data. Unfortunately, that isn't easy considering the way OpenCV will store the data (x1, y1, z1), (x1, y1, z2), (x1, y1, z3), etc. instead of (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y1, z1), (x3, y1, z1), etc. I'd suggest marol's solution, so that your data is stored in the correct manner.