# Reading images into vec<Mat> 16bit error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to read a 3D image (stored as binary file) into a vector of Mat (so that I could read slice by slice) but always giving me segmentation error when trying to run create_mat. I'm struggling to find what went wrong. Is this the best way to read the data in the first place ?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void read_tiff(string filename,unsigned long length,uint16_t* buffer)
{
  //Reads a binary file containing little endean array of uint16_t into a single array pointed by buffer
  FILE *ptr_file;
  ptr_file = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
  rewind(ptr_file);
  uint16_t temp;
  unsigned int k;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    {
      fread(&temp,2,1,ptr_file);
      buffer[k] = temp;     
    }  
  fclose(ptr_file);
  return;
}
void create_mat(vector<Mat> dst,const int width,const int height,const int stacks,uint16_t* src)
{
  int i,j,k;
  int counter = 0;
   for (i=0;i<stacks;i++)
    {
      for (j=0;j<height;j++)
    {
      for (k=0;k<width;k++)
        {
          (dst[i]).at<ushort>(j,k)= src[counter];
          cout<<src[counter]<<endl;
          //          cout<<dst[i].at<ushort>(j,k)<<endl;
          counter++;
        }
    }
    }

}
int main()
{
  string dir;
  dir = "/somedir.raw";
  cout<<dir<<std::endl;
  unsigned long length = 1365ul*1531ul*1265ul;
  uint16_t test[length];
  read_tiff(dir,length,test);
  int size[3] = {1265,1365,1531};
  vector<Mat> img(size[0],Mat(size[1],size[2],CV_16UC1)); 
  cout <<"image loading done"<<endl;
  create_mat(img,size[1],size[2],size[0],test);
  imwrite("test.jpg",img[400]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your create_mat function makes a copy of vector<Mat> img. Do you mean to pass it by reference instead?

Comment: maybe not the error but vector<Mat> img(size[0],Mat(size[1],size[2],CV_16UC1));  will lead to problems since each vector element (=each Mat) will link to the same data memory!

Comment: width and height are swapped. Mat constructor is Mat(height,width,...)

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the response!! I thought I was allocating size[0] number of empty matrices, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998422/how-to-access-slices-of-a-3d-matrix-in-opencv

Comment: @BasinhetVeld vector<Mat>* dst ?

Comment: @Micka also the height and width order shouldn't be a problem as the image would just be transposed right ?

Comment: no, you access some row and column of the image and you will exceed the image bounds if it is wrong, leading to segmentation faults or access errors. Imagine you have height 4 and width 6, so 24 elements, and you try to access element (y,x) then it will compute the address like y*width + x. So if you try to access last row last element (3,5), but you swap the order, you'll get 5*6+3 = element number 33.

Comment: it would be no problem if you were consistent in wrong constructor + wrong access, but you use constructor `Mat(width, height,..)` and access like `.at<ushort>(y,x)`. RIGHT way would be `Mat(height, width,..)` and access `.at<ushort>(y,x)`. Transposed would be `Mat(width, height,..)` with access `.at<ushort>(x,y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, which fixes the 2 problems I mentioned in the comments:

Code changes are marked by `CHANGED:`

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void read_tiff(string filename,unsigned long length,uint16_t* buffer)
{
  //Reads a binary file containing little endean array of uint16_t into a single array pointed by buffer
  FILE *ptr_file;
  ptr_file = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
  rewind(ptr_file);
  uint16_t temp;
  unsigned int k;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    {
      fread(&temp,2,1,ptr_file);
      buffer[k] = temp;     
    }  
  fclose(ptr_file);
  return;
}
void create_mat(vector<Mat> dst,const int width,const int height,const int stacks,uint16_t* src)
{
  int i,j,k;
  int counter = 0;
   for (i=0;i<stacks;i++)
    {
      for (j=0;j<height;j++)
    {
      for (k=0;k<width;k++)
        {
          (dst[i]).at<ushort>(j,k)= src[counter];
          cout<<src[counter]<<endl;
          //          cout<<dst[i].at<ushort>(j,k)<<endl;
          counter++;
        }
    }
    }

}
int main()
{
  string dir;
  dir = "/somedir.raw";
  cout<<dir<<std::endl;
  unsigned long length = 1365ul*1531ul*1265ul;
  uint16_t test[length];
  read_tiff(dir,length,test);
  int size[3] = {1265,1365,1531};
  // CHANGED: Instead of allocating Mat memory once and copy-constructing the Mat-header, create a new Mat header + memory for each vector element. Otherwise all the elements will share their pixel data (if you don't call a function that assigns new memory to the Mat)
  //vector<Mat> img(size[0],Mat(size[1],size[2],CV_16UC1)); 
  vector<Mat> img(size[0]);
  for(int i=0; i<size[0]; ++i)
      img[i] = Mat(size[2],size[1],CV_16UC1); // CHANGED: swapped height and width, because Mat constructor uses height-first


  cout <<"image loading done"<<endl;
  create_mat(img,size[1],size[2],size[0],test);
  imwrite("test.jpg",img[400]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does it.